# How to insert metatag only in static URL

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I need to add a specific metatag `robots` with property noindex/nofollow to only specific URL of my site, for example:

```
www.example.com/static/:somestaticURL
```

I tried with this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-metatag

But it doesn't seem to add the tag. Here is my code:

```js
let Meta = require('express-metatag')

let robotMetaTag =  Meta('robots', true)({
    tag: 'noindex,nofollow'
})

app.get('/static/:staticURL',function(req,res){
    app.use(robotMetaTag);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

@Gabriela,

The easiest way would be to add the `<meta>` tag for robots in the HTML page that can be accessed using that static URL. Sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome, please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).